# How to have Guile on Ubuntu interpret Scheme source file?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, guile

First of all this might be really basic thing but I do not know how to proceed. I have `Guile 2.0.9` and `Libctl 3.2.2` installed on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS. My aim is to write a source file in `Scheme` then have it interpret by `Guile` so I do not spend too much time on the prompt trying to correct some minor errors(correcting errors on a file is much easier). How can I have it read and execute the contents of my source file?

Comment: Also, you can use `(load "myfile.scm")` to evaluate a whole file. You don't have to make the file executable to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run .scm source file as a command line program you have to add at the head of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile -s
!#
```

where you must specify proper path to you `guile` executable. You can find location of `guile` by

```
which guile
```

and you will get something like `/usr/bin/guile`

And do not forget to make you file executable:

```
chmode +x file.scm
```

If you want to set particular entry point to your program than there is another way to start script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile \
-e main -s
!#
```

`-e` option specify a program entry point function name.

For example `file.scm`

```
#!/usr/bin/guile \
-e main -s
!#
(define (main args)
    (display "Hello ")
    (write (cdr args))
    (newline))
```

Now let run it

```
[root@tuxbox ~]# ./file.scm Jim
Hello ("Jim")
```

Comment: A better example of "Hello Jim" would be to use `(format #t "Hello ~a~%" (cadr args))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so it is essentially like a `bash` script? But why do we have the `!#` line?

Comment: The first line starts with `#!` to inform operation system how to interpret the script, but also it opens the multiple line comment block. So we have to add `!#` line to inform `guile` that comment block is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You will find that information in [guile documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Handling.html).